# How to get the fully-qualified target of a MethodInvocation?

Tags: dart, abstract-syntax-tree, static-analysis

I'm trying to find usages of a particular method. In this case, I want to find usages/invocations of `foo.go()`, but NOT `bar.go()`. The below code will find all invocations of `go()` on ANY class. In the code below, `node.target` gives me simply `x` which is the var name, but I'm struggling to figure out which class the method belongs to.

#### test.dart

```
void main() {
  var x = new Foo();
  x.go();

  x = new Bar();
  x.go();
}

class Foo {
  go() {
    print('I am foo');
  }
}

class Bar {
  go() {
    print('I am bar');
  }
}
```

#### analyze.dart

```
import 'package:analyzer/analyzer.dart';
import 'package:analyzer/dart/ast/ast.dart';
import 'package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart';

void main() {
  var targetFile = parseDartFile('test.dart');
  var visitor    = new UsageVisitor('foo.go');
  targetFile.visitChildren(visitor);
}

class UsageVisitor extends UnifyingAstVisitor {
  String _class;
  String _method;

  UsageVisitor(this._class, this._method);

  @override
  visitMethodInvocation(MethodInvocation node) {
    print({
      'target'    : node.target.toString(),    // in both cases, gives "x" -- I need "Foo" and "Bar", respectively
      'methodName': node.methodName.toString() // gives "go"
    });

    return super.visitNode(node);
  }
}
```

---

**How do I tell the difference (at the analyzer level), between `foo.go()` and `bar.go()` ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `test.dart` is being **parsed without context** needed to resolve the elements contained within.

An example of this is included in the [analyzer package within the Dart SDK](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/pkg/analyzer/example/resolver_driver.dart)

Breaking that down to its steps you have:

#### 1 - Setup resolvers

```
PhysicalResourceProvider resourceProvider = PhysicalResourceProvider.INSTANCE;
DartSdk sdk = new FolderBasedDartSdk(resourceProvider, resourceProvider.getFolder(args[0]));

var resolvers = [
  new DartUriResolver(sdk),
  new ResourceUriResolver(resourceProvider)
];
```

### 2 - Create an `AnalysisContext` using the resolvers

```
AnalysisContext context = AnalysisEngine.instance.createAnalysisContext()
  ..sourceFactory = new SourceFactory(resolvers);
```

### 3 - Add your `Source` to a `ChangeSet`

```
Source source = new FileSource(resourceProvider.getFile(args[1]));
ChangeSet changeSet = new ChangeSet()..addedSource(source);
```

#### 3.1 - Apply the `ChangeSet` to the `AnalysisContext`

```
context.applyChanges(changeSet);
```

#### 3.2 - Get the `LibraryElement`

*I'm not certain if this is always needed. Maybe it can be skipped for simple files.* ¯(◉◡◔)/¯

```
LibraryElement libElement = context.computeLibraryElement(source);
```

### 4 - Parse your `Source`!

```
CompilationUnit resolvedUnit = context.resolveCompilationUnit(source, libElement);
```

### 5 - Run your `Visitor`

```
resolvedUnit.accept(visitor)
```

Unfortunately that's *a lot* more code than just calling `parseDartFile()` but the good news is that your `Visitor` should work without further changes.

Good luck!

Comment: This is amazing! Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

I found something, but I am not used to the analyzer, maybe it can be simplify and it works only for you case.

```
@override
visitMethodInvocation(MethodInvocation node) {
  if (node.methodName.toString() == "go" && node.target.toString() == "x") {
    for (dynamic child in node.parent?.parent?.childEntities) {
      if (child is VariableDeclarationStatement) {
        if ((child.childEntities.first as VariableDeclarationList).type.toString() == "Foo" &&
          ((child.childEntities.first as VariableDeclarationList).childEntities.elementAt(1) as VariableDeclaration)
                  .beginToken
                  .toString() ==
              "x") {
          print(node);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return super.visitNode(node);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but you're right, this only works on my very simple example code. As soon as you get into "real" (more complex) code and introduce if/else blocks, closures, methods, classes, etc, this approach becomes untenable.